# How will the following crop function on python crop a image using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

In the below function  `imcrop_tosquare`.
Assume i have a image of shape (8,4)
ie 8 rows and 4 column.
If that is the case. I will be getting extra as 4.
Then `extra%2 ==0` condition gets satisfied.

```
crop = img[2:-2,:]
```

What does 2 to -2 represent?
I assume it is from 2nd row to its before row.
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 [This will be in loop] so -1 would be 1 and -2 would be 2.
Wont the image be damaged if bring the first two rows to end??
Am i interpreting it wrongly? Can anyone guide me in understanding this.

```
def imcrop_tosquare(img):
"""Make any image a square image.

Parameters
----------
img : np.ndarray
    Input image to crop, assumed at least 2d.

Returns
-------
crop : np.ndarray
    Cropped image.
"""
  if img.shape[0] > img.shape[1]:
    extra = (img.shape[0] - img.shape[1])
    if extra % 2 == 0:
        crop = img[extra // 2:-extra // 2, :]
    else:
        crop = img[max(0, extra // 2 + 1):min(-1, -(extra // 2)), :]
  elif img.shape[1] > img.shape[0]:
    extra = (img.shape[1] - img.shape[0])
    if extra % 2 == 0:
        crop = img[:, extra // 2:-extra // 2]
    else:
        crop = img[:, max(0, extra // 2 + 1):min(-1, -(extra // 2))]
  else:
    print("It is imgae")
    crop = img
  return crop
```

Comment: You should read numpy documentation. It has the answers to all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

according to [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) :

> Negative i and j are interpreted as n + i and n + j where n is the number of elements in the corresponding dimension.

so if you have 8 rows in your array, `crop = img[2:-2,:]` would mean `crop = img[2:6,:]`